# SSRS Matrix - Sorting rows by a specific column

Tags: sorting, matrix, reporting-services, pivot

Can somebody explain me how to properly sort "[Arrivals] group" by Count(SearchDate)] for particular "Departure" in this Matrix?

[image]

I tried this fx in Row Group Sorting Properities, but it didn't work.

```
[Count(SearchDate)]
```

Then I tried specify which column I would like to sort, but same problem.

```
=Count(IIF(Fields!Departures.Value = "PRG", 1, 0))
```

After deeper inspection I found that I am able to sort "[Arrivals] group" only by [Count(SearchDate)] but not grouped for particular "Departure".

[image]

After a advice in MSDN forum I tried this fx:

```
=IIF(Fields!Departures.Value = "PRG", Count(Fields!SearchDate.Value), 0)
```

In first view result looks good but only for the first couple of records.

When I tried pivot table in SQL server everything looks fine:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Arrivals, Departures, SearchDate FROM Destination WHERE SearchDate > '2016-03-01T00:00:00' AND SearchDate < '2016-03-28T14:03:46') as a
PIVOT (COUNT(SearchDate) for Departures in (PRG, LON)) as PivotTable
Order by PRG Desc
```

I spent a lot of time and tried a lot of solution but I have realy no idea how to solve it.

Thank you very much for your help, Petr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem before. Try using this expression:

```
=COUNT(
  IIF(
    Fields!Departures.Value="PRG",
    COUNT(Fields!SearchDate.Value),
    Nothing
  )
 )
```

It could be a pain since depending on the dataset number of rows it increases the report processing time causing poor performance, it works though.

Let me know if this helps.